# Не работает валидация форм с помощью Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, form, валидация

Доброго времени суток, форумчане!

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает валидация формы. Делаю всё, как тут:
[jQuery Validate Demo](http://alittlecode.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery-Validate-Demo/index.html?name=tyuteu&email=rtye%40kkre.kotre&subject=ghresh&message=sryhresy)
и тут
[Validate a Form using jQuery and Bootstrap Validator](http://www.devcurry.com/2014/08/validate-form-using-jquery-and_5.html)

Может что-то не так с файлом скрипта? Или подключаю его как-то не так?
Код скрипта, взятый из примера и переделанный под мои нужды:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#timeValidationForm').bootstrapValidator({
        container: '#messages',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            time: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The full name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 5,
                    message: 'Input must be larger than 1 and less than 5'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Код html. Нужно заметить, что валидация поля происходит в модальном окне и должна работать без нажатия кнопки "submit":

```
@using( Html.BeginForm("ClockChanger", "Clocks", FormMethod.Post, new{@id="timeValidationForm", @class="form-horizontal"} ) )
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Time</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time" placeholder="Time in minutes" />
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
              <div id="messages"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <div class="div_buttons_modal">
           <button type="submit" class="My_Button">Yes</button>
       </div>
       <div class="div_buttons_modal">
           <button type="button" class="My_Button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
       </div>
   </div>
}
```

Скрипт подключаю в теге **`<head>`** с помощью **`<script>`**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ValidationForm.js"></script>
```

Comment: Разместите отрендеренный html код и скрипты на jsfiddle.net, тогда гораздо проще будет выяснить

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В коде инициализации валидатора ошибка - скобка поставлена неверно и поле `stringLength` не входит в объект `validators`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#timeValidationForm').bootstrapValidator({
        container: '#messages',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            time: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The full name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 5,
                        message: 'Input must be larger than 1 and less than 5'
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Исправленный вариант в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2ofu74j/).

Comment: поправила, но валидация по-прежнему не осуществляется. Никаких видимых признаков того, что она работает на форме. Предполагается, что как только я введу что-то в поле и щёлкну в любое место формы, не нажимая кнопку "submit", должна осуществляться проверка. Но, это не происходит. Может данное решение не позволяет осуществить то, что хочется, и как-то нужно дополнить скрипт, чтобы он менял название класса тега input на has-success????

Comment: @cat_woman, когда в примере ввожу данные в поле, сообщения о пустом поле и о превышении длины высвечиваются, может у вас адблокер скрипты блокирует или несколько форм с одинаковыми id, а ещё гляньте в консоль разработчика на предмет ошибок

Comment: спасибо!!! Посмотрела в вашем решении, что в моём не хватало файла: <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>. Пишут, что смогу вам вручить награду через 21 час))) Ждите)

Comment: а может ещё заодно подскажете, как сделать проверку на тип вводимых данных: число или нет?

Comment: @cat_woman вот тут список всех валидаторов http://formvalidation.io/validators/ ,   digits  вам как раз подойдёт:
                    digits: {
                         message: 'Numbers ples'
                    }

Comment: а что делать, если таких форм, к примеру, несколько на одной странице и они одинаковые? Скрипт всегда подцепляет только первую форму, а остальные не проверяет((

Comment: @cat_woman, вы, вероятно используете одни и те же айдишники для форм, но по правилам id должен быть уникален. Посему просто поменяйте #messages #timeValidationForm на селекторы для классов и не забудьте поменять атрибуты id на class в вёрстке